# How to make a http GET request with chrome on android using referer

Tags: android, get, user-agent, http-referer, webresource

I am trying to solve an interesting problem

Using chrome on an Android device

1. create a http GET request to a resource and make it appear like you are following a link to that resource from another web page.

In general we use just

```
GET <web-service_URL>/<PATH_TO_RESOURCE>
```

to get content from a resource. How can we make it look like we are following a link to that resource from an another web page?

Comment: Then you have to supply a referrer. But what do you mean by 'Using chrome' ?

Comment: Chrome browser from an android phone. Do anyone know if chrome on android has an extension to explicitly send a GET request?

Comment: Is it possible we can do this using User agent and referrer on desktop browser?